# Asterisk/FreePBX: how to reject all incoming calls after few seconds?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, gsm

I have 3 dumb GSM relays that control the gates. If a person whose number is in device's address book calls, gate opens. Call gets rejected (in my country calls that didn't connect or lasted less than 5 seconds are free).

The problem with this setup is that rejected calls do not appear in the operator's call data register (CDR) and, thus, in online statement. I had no means to check who exactly opened the gate at given time.

**As a workaround I enabled SIP for those 3 numbers.** Operator simultaneously routes the incoming call to GSM modem over air and to SIP account where I see Caller ID.

Trouble is that now I have to use 3 ancient Android phones with operator's SIP app to log incoming calls. It works, but it is a weird inconvenient kludge. Plus, it breaks the user experience of my neighbours - they got used that their call gets dropped instantly by GSM relay, and now they will hear rings until SIP app decides to reject the call.

I have an old netbook where I've installed FreePBX distro. I will add those 3 SIP accounts to it. **I need an advice on how to configure Asterisk to record the Caller ID of every incoming SIP call plus its date and time in its MySQL database, *wait* few seconds and *reject* call.** I'll later write a simple Perl script to look into this database and make a neat HTML report for me.

I get that this must be very simple, but this sort of setup is weird use case for Asterisk and I can't find any existing HOWTOs on it.

P.S. Editing GSM relay firmware to make it accept and immediately reject call is *not* an option - it is proprietary.

Comment: Just need to check I understand; are the calls coming in via SIP lines or via GSM lines? And are you trying to condense this solution down into something more simple/small? Asterisk config is possible and I can help you out once I've double checked I understand your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, sorted out this problem already. All it took was to add 5 sec delay

Comment: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/04/27/0000/3204/15492/92/30aada3022.jpg and then hang up: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/04/27/0000/3204/15492/92/8ea3b66518.jpg And yes, calls arrive through SIP.

Comment: no worries glad you got it sorted.